# Stackdriver Logging - Log severity levels not reported/received when sent via syslog

Tags: google-cloud-platform, syslog, rsyslog, google-cloud-logging, google-cloud-stackdriver

It appears that log severity is not being passed to Google Cloud Logging platform via fluentd agent, to reproduce you can try:

**Bash:**

`logger -p user.crit "My log"`

**or PHP:**

`php -r "syslog(LOG_CRIT,'My log');"`

**or Python:**

```
import syslog

syslog.syslog(syslog.LOG_ERR, 'My log')
```

things are getting passed to Google Logs Viewer as below:

[image]

but severity is not being sent across, any ideas why would that be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, managed to find the solution, here you go:

1. update your syslog output format under `/etc/rsyslog.conf` to the following:

   ```
   $template googlelogger,"%syslogseverity-text% %timegenerated% %HOSTNAME% %syslogtag% %msg%\n"
   $ActionFileDefaultTemplate googlelogger
   ```
2. then update `/etc/google-fluentd/config.d/syslog.conf` template format:

   ```
   format /^(?<severity>[a-zA-Z]*) (?<time>[^ ]*\s*[^ ]* [^ ]*) (?<host>[^ ]*) (?<service>[a-zA-Z0-9_\/\.\-]*): *(?<message>.*)$/
   time_format %b %d %H:%M:%S
   ```

make sure to restart both `rsyslog` and `google-fluentd` after that severity will be sent to Google Cloud Logging